# Not able to run next commands in Tkinter once a button command is triggered

Tags: python, url, tkinter, jira, python-webbrowser

I am creating a python scripts which will open a new JIRA URL every time i click on the Next button by changing the JIRA Case Id embedded in the URL. But when I click the Next Button first time to execute the command, the window stops responding and i am not able to click again in the Tkinter window. If i close the opened Browser, then only it lets me do other actions.

The code below will read the URL from the Entry widget and increment/decrement the case Id `PROJ-T00` if clicked on Next or Prev button and open the updated URL.

When i click on any one button, the URL opens, but i cannot click on these buttons again until I close the opened Browser Window.

Using lambda also did not solve the problem

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
import os


root = Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.geometry("600x150")

newTab = IntVar()
newBrowser = IntVar()
input_url = StringVar()
chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'
initURL = 'https://jira.****.***/../testCase/PROJ-T01'

def nextUrl():
    url = input_url.get()
    baseUrl = url.rsplit('T', 1)[0] + 'T'
    curentCaseId = int(url.rsplit('T', 1)[-1])
    caseId = curentCaseId + 1
    url = baseUrl + str(caseId)
    print(url)
    name_entry.delete(0,"end")
    name_entry.insert(0, url)
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url,new=0)

def prevUrl():
    url = input_url.get()
    baseUrl = url.rsplit('T', 1)[0] + 'T'
    curentCaseId = int(url.rsplit('T', 1)[-1])
    caseId = curentCaseId - 1
    url = baseUrl + str(caseId)
    print(url)
    name_entry.delete(0,"end")
    name_entry.insert(0, url)
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url,new=0)  
    
def openUrl():
    print(input_url.get())
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(input_url.get(),new=0)

select_msg = Label(root, text = "Current URL")
name_entry = Entry(root, textvariable = input_url, font=('calibre',10,'normal'), width=83)
name_entry.insert(0, initURL)
l1 = Checkbutton(root, text='Open in New Tab', variable=newTab, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
l2 = Checkbutton(root, text='Open in New Browser', variable=newBrowser, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
prev = Button(root, text = 'Prev Case', command= prevUrl)
open = Button(root, text = 'Open Case', command= openUrl)
next = Button(root, text = 'Next Case', command= nextUrl)

select_msg.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan=3)
name_entry.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=3,padx = 5)
l1.grid(row=2,column=0)
l2.grid(row=2,column=2)
prev.grid(row=3,column=0)
open.grid(row=3,column=1)
next.grid(row=3,column=2)

root.mainloop()

`
```

Comment: Try running the `webbrowser.get(...).open(...)` in another thread.

Comment: @TheLizzard URL opens for the first time. Only then the window stops responding until I close the opened Browser.

Comment: Is that after you started using another thread? I think the problem is that the `webbrowser.get(...).open(...)` stops `tkinter` from updating the window so it becomes unresponsive until the end of the `webbrowser.get(...).open(...)` (when the web browser is closed)

Comment: @TheLizzard I removed the ```.get(...)``` command from here so that it uses the default browser. Now it works fine with default Edge Browser. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling the `webbrowser` from another thread? It is possible that Edge and Chrome act differently when asked to open a website.

Comment: Are you sure the new URLs are correct? `int('01')` -> 1